# Chrome extension to add event in google calendar('background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner for the chrome extension. I have found a demo to add event to google calendar, I have solved some problems for this demo, but it doesn't word yet... Now I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it

```
L'installation de cette extension a généré des avertissements :
'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.
```

manifest.json :

```
{
"name": "Add Event to Google Calendar",
"version": "1.4.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "A user can add events to Google Calendar by simply highlighting dates that appear on a webpage.",
"icons": { "48": "calendar48.png", "128": "calendar128.png" },
"background_page": "background.html",
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "http://www.google.com/"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "date.js", "content_script.js"]
    }
]
}
```

background.html

I can not post `background.html` here, because it is too long...please download this here [Add-to-Calendar-Chrome-Extension](https://github.com/joshholat/Add-to-Calendar-Chrome-Extension)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google are changing the manifest version requirements for Chrome as detailed in this [link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html).

The warning is only visible with "Developer mode" active. They don't affect end-user. You can also consider using [`minimum_chrome_version`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest#minimum_chrome_version) to block users with older browsers from downloading your latest update. Downgrade to `manifest_version: 1`, wait for everyone to download downgraded version and, yet again, push update with `manifest_version: 2` this time adding `minimum_chrome_version: 18`.

The `background_page` property has been replaced with a background. That property contains scripts, either a page or property. Details are available in the [Event Pages documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

You may check this [forum](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2077).